# source map minified source to single unminified source with pseudo files

Tags: requirejs, r.js, uglifyjs, source-maps

I have a scenario in which I can't upload all of the sources to the server, which means if I source map to a minified file the inspector won't resolve the mapped resources because they don't exist on the server.

Is it possible to generate three files such that the minified source is mapped to a single file with all of the sources, but that single source is interpreted as many individual files in the inspector? This way all of the sources need not exist on the server, only three files: minified, map, and unminified.

I can't find any options for this in UglifyJS, but perhaps there's another compiler that supports it, or is this a limitation of the Source Map spec?

The only workaround I can think of for the moment is compiling all of my files to a single optimised file w/ r.js and then mapping that file. Unfortunately then I will lose the ability to find line numbers within individual files and navigate the source easily.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that uglify2 does this by default.
The feature I was describing above is inlining sourcesContent in a source map.